# Can not create href link with # char in XSLT transformation

Tags: html, string, xslt, char, href

I have problem with char "#" in creating internal link with href: so my code is:

```
     <xsl:template match="content">
        <p><h3><a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="#../@number"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a></h3></p>
      </xsl:template>
```

and I have no idea how what is wrong with this code: `select="#../@number"`

Comment: Isn't `#` a literal value which should be outside the `<xsl:value-of select=""/>` bit?

Comment: Yes, of course it is too late for me. Thanks for advice, solved.